# Passing data to modal:Property/method props undefined & TypeError: Cannot read property product of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, vue-props

I have a product listing, each contains some information and a button. The button(more details button) when clicked opens a modal window that contains that specific product's(I used props to pass data from parent to child) further information. I have a root component(parent: App.vue) under which I have a product listing component(child: Product_listing.vue) and a modal window component(grandchild: Modal_window.vue) in Vue. I suppose the child and grandchild also share a parent-child relationship and hence I used props here. I keep getting these errors:

1. `Property or method "props" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`
2. `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined.`
3. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined.`

This is what I have so far and I've been following this example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5tgq4dof/1/

**PARENT COMPONENT(Product_listing.vue)**

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="nested" v-for="product in products">
            <div class="one"><span>{{product.Name}}</span></div>
            <div class="two"><span>-{{ product.Reduction_percentage }}%</span></div>       
            <div class="three"><span>{{ product.Short_Description }}</span></div>
            <div class="four"><b-btn id="show-modal" class="more_details_button" @click="selectProduct(product)">More details</b-btn></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
Vue.component('Modal_window', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  props:['product', 'open']
})

export default {
  data () {
    return {
        showModal: false,
        selectedProduct: undefined,
        products: [
              {id: 1, Name: 'Product 1', Reduction_percentage: 30, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 2, Name: 'Product 2', Reduction_percentage: 33, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 3, Name: 'Product 3', Reduction_percentage: 23, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 4, Name: 'Product 4', Reduction_percentage: 77, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 5, Name: 'Product 5', Reduction_percentage: 99, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
          ],
    }
},
    methods: {
      selectProduct(product) {
      this.selectedProduct = product
      this.showModal = true
    }
}

}


</script>
```

**Child component(Modal_window.vue)**

```
<template id="modal-template">
<b-modal v-show="showModal" :product="selectedProduct" hide-footer="true" ok-title="Buy Now" size="lg" :title="product.Name">
            <div class = "inner-container">
                <div class = "inner-nested">
                    <div class="inner-one"><br> {{product.Description}}</div>
                    <div class="inner-two">
                        -{{ product.Reduction_percentage }}%</div>  
                    <div class="inner-three"> <button>Buy Now</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-modal>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Product_listing.vue
// change the line by adding :product="product"
<div class="four">
    <b-btn id="show-modal" 
       class="more_details_button" 
       @click="selectProduct(product)" 
       :product="product">More details</b-btn>
```

```
// Modal_window.vue
// add the script section so that the component has a props entry for product
<template id="modal-template">
<b-modal v-show="showModal" :product="selectedProduct" hide-footer="true" ok-title="Buy Now" size="lg" :title="product.Name">
            <div class = "inner-container">
                <div class = "inner-nested">
                    <div class="inner-one"><br> {{product.Description}}</div>
                    <div class="inner-two">
                        -{{ product.Reduction_percentage }}%</div>  
                    <div class="inner-three"> <button>Buy Now</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-modal>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            product: { type: Object, default: null}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! I managed to solve the errors and followed what you did, but now the modal window does not open, also, I modified my question a bit from 
`Vue.component('Modal-component', {
 ...
})`
to 
`Vue.component('Modal_window', {
 ...
})`
sorry about that.